# Unable To Set Datatextfield and dataValuefield When Loading To ComboBox From SQL (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, drop-down-menu, combobox, datatable

I have method where I retrieve datatable and I am trying load to combobox and it works fine but I am unable set Datatextfield and DataValuefield when I try to it shows error indicating does not contain defintion.

here is code snippet of method to retrieve datatable

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id,CampaignName FROM CampaignsTable", sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    using (SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dtTable.Load(sqlDataReader);
                        sqlDataReader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            return dtTable;
```

Below Code Snippet on Loading to combobox

```
drpDownProfiles.DataSource = rank.RetrieveProjectNames();
drpDownProfiles.DataTextField = "Not Working";
drpDownProfiles.DataValueField = "Not Working";
```

Comment: It's not a winforms/wpf `ComboBox` but an ASP.NET `DropDownList`, isn't it?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter its for winforms i messed the names

Answer (score 0):

These two properties:

```
drpDownProfiles.DataTextField = "Not Working";
drpDownProfiles.DataValueField = "Not Working";
```

should be set up like:

```
drpDownProfiles.DataTextField = "CampaignName";
drpDownProfiles.DataValueField = "Id";
```

Comment: thanks for your reply I know that I was using not working shows in those statement i am getting on words DataTextField and DataValueField. Thats what I am not able to figure out

Comment: above solution did not work so i used text to setup and used a switch statement to set a value.